# Vertical alignment of multiple spans in a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, tablecell

Just like the header suggests: how does one align multiple span elements in a div? I've tried table-cell and vertical alignment features, but they seem not to work for multiple spans, only works well for one. How do I go around this?

Comment: One include the code on the question itself and your try .... then you can understand better what is wrong with your code.

Comment: What isn't working with table cells http://cssdeck.com/labs/wyxdemep ?

Answer (score 0):

why you need to use span element inside div. Try to use nested div and set width for all div tags. You also needs to set few more properties if  you want all div to come in 1 line. Google that.

Comment: That's the problem, it's a little more complex. So basically I have an address div, which contains 3 spans: one with the address itself, and two with phone numbers. The purpose is to make sure that upon resizing they all stay together nicely i.e. half of the address is not gonna appear next line with a phone number. And also, I have media queries to change the font-size upon window resizing. But when it resizes - the font becomes too small and aligns to the top, instead of vertically spreading out evenly. So, basically, I want the spans to evenly take up the vertical space. @user3610891

Comment: the best way to align all this is to use tables. In my project for every layout we use tables inside div tags. And they overtake the extra overhead of managing div and span tags.